# How to refactor React Native function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to refactor the follow function but not sure how. I dont won't to use useWindowDimensions.

current code

```
Dimensions.addEventListener('change', ({window:{width,height}})=>{
      if (width<height) {
        setOrientation("PORTRAIT")
      } else {
        setOrientation("LANDSCAPE")
    
      }
    })
```

I like to convert it into:

```
 const _onOrientationDidChange = (deviceOrientation) => {
   // get screen Dimensions
  };


useEffect(()=>{
    const screenInfo = Dimensions.addEventListener('change', _onOrientationDidChange)

    return ()=>{
        screenInfo.remove()
    }
},[])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling `_onOrientationDidChange` function in `addEventListener`.

```
const _onOrientationDidChange = ({ window }) => {
    // get screen Dimensions
    const { height, width } = window;
    if (width < height) {
      setOrientation('PORTRAIT');
    } else {
      setOrientation('LANDSCAPE');
    }
  };

useEffect(() => {
    const screenInfo = Dimensions.addEventListener(
      'change',
      _onOrientationDidChange()
    );

    return () => screenInfo?.remove();
  });
```